# Import error when calling the file in different folders

Tags: python, python-3.x

Before I start explaining my problem here is my directory structure:

```
└── github  (folder)
    └── bleeding  (folder)
        ├── testing.py   (main file)
        └── core  (folder)
            ├── __init__.py
            └── sample.py
```

Whenever I call the `sample.py` from my main file, I get an error.

I am calling the sample.py file like this

```
from core.sample import sample
```

and I get this error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'sample' from 'core.sample'

And another thing: I would like to know how can I call my main file (testing.py) back after when user is done with second file, do I need to call it the same way like this like from folder.file import file?

Edit :
added a function in my second file (sample.py) 
But now only my main file is running when i try to call second file it still shows the same import error

Comment: Do you have a function `def sample` in `sample.py`?

Comment: is this a typo? from core.smaple import sample

Comment: no i dont have any function in second file

Comment: from which directory are you running the code and from where (terminal, some IDE) ?

Comment: @clear_walrus if you dont have a function named sample in samply py then ofc you will get import error

Comment: Ok so i made a function in my second file but now only my main file is running when i try to call the second it still throws me the same error calling it now like this from core.sample import sam

Comment: Please post the contents of the two files. Make this as simple as possible.